# Is there a Dreamweaver HTML editor replacement?

Tags: software-recommendation, html

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Basic Web Development IDE/Editor like Dreamweaver?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/59632/basic-web-development-ide-editor-like-dreamweaver)

I used Adobe's Dreamweaver for working on web pages and various text editors. I already have a few favorite text editors but couldn't find a good replacement for Dreamweaver? Is there any recommended HTML WYSIWYG editors? Thanks!