# Best editor for ubuntu

Tags: programming, 9.10, editor

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a Dreamweaver HTML editor replacement?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/7391/is-there-a-dreamweaver-html-editor-replacement)

Hello 
Can anybody suggest me the best editor for ubuntu(9.10) for programming purpose like dreamweaver.and also the command how to install this editor on system.

Comment: If you have another question to ask - then [Ask](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) it in a different question.

Comment: hello sir at the end of my question display[closed],what it mean?

Answer (score 7):

I recommend vim.

It is highly customizable. Its learning curve is a bit tough, but possibilities are almost endless.

Here is [tutorial](http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/LinuxTutorialAdvanced_vi.html) with installation tips and other useful stuff.

Comment: I m trying to install but give some error

Comment: ubc@ubc-desktop:~$ apt-get install vim vim-common vim-gnome vim-gui-common vim-runtime
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), are you root?

Comment: try sudo apt-get install vim vim-common vim-gnome vim-gui-common vim-runtime

Comment: it successfully run. It installed or need any other step need ?

Comment: thats it, So you can read tutorial now))

Comment: I would not suggest `vim` as a replacement for dreamweaver. The learning curve from one to the other is more than "a bit tough".

Comment: You might want to try the list of resources here: http://net.tutsplus.com/articles/web-roundups/25-vim-tutorials-screencasts-and-resources/

Comment: `vim` as `Dreamweaver` replacement!? Came on people, this answer does not deserve it's score. There are bunch of users, which recommend either `vim` or `emacs` for anything in question. It's same horde of supporters

Answer (score 5):

[geany](http://geany.org)
Install with `sudo apt-get install geany geany-plugins`

Answer (score 3):

I would prefer netbeans and eclipse. Both are available on software center.

Comment: I dont know about linux.can u please tell me whole procedure.Thanks

Comment: ok i found the software center

Comment: Hope you have successfully installed it. if you feel any difficulties feel free to post it here.

Comment: ok again thanks for reply.I m installing but it taking time

Comment: here is a similar post:  http://askubuntu.com/questions/7391/is-there-a-dreamweaver-html-editor-replacement

Comment: I have installed netbeans but how to open a file in this editor?and also where i can see this installed editor?

Comment: To open a file click on the file menu and select the 'open file' option. Usually it will create an icon on the desktop. if it is not there you can open it from the appliations -> Programming -> netbeans ide

Comment: I open a php file in both editor but it not highlight php code and also not html tag it show file content like when i paste some code in nodepad.need any setting?

Comment: By default ubuntu provide gedit but in this i m not able to find start tag and closin tag thats why i need other editor.

Comment: I guess the best editor is up to the use and how/where you want to apply the application.

Comment: Eclipse is a bit heavy and can be draggy based from my experience. It also has a very large support and plugins.

Comment: @shalu:  Eclipse and netbeans are for serious project development. If you are looking for a simple lightweight editor, probably to edit single files with some additional features like syntax highlighting ,code folding etc. then 'geany' is for you. available at software center.

Answer (score 2):

It is a same question like this.

[Is there a Dreamweaver HTML editor replacement?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/7391/is-there-a-dreamweaver-html-editor-replacement)

Answer (score 1):

You may also be happy with [Gedit](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/gedit), the GNOME standard editor that is already installed in Ubuntu. There are many options and [plugins](http://live.gnome.org/Gedit/Plugins#third_party) available for configuring Gedit to meet your needs.

Comment: I have tried all advanced option that provided with gedit.But I m not able to find the end tag(html).Mean suppose i take mouse over  a <div id="f1"> tag and i want to find  the end  of this div tag than it not show like this option.

Comment: Thats why I need other editor.In dreamweaver when take mouseover a div tag and then right click it show the option select current tag area.it will highligted that particular div.We can easily found how many <div> start and how many close.I m not figure out any help regard this.

Comment: I edited my answer for links to various plugins.

Answer (score 0):

dreamweaver is not an editor but a good solution for the web in Linux is [Aptana](http://www.aptana.com/). It is not WYSIWYG. To install it, only downlad unzip it (if necessary) and run it. Aptana will create a folder "workspace" (I´m not soure about the name) to your home folder and thats all.

Comment: Dreamweaver is an editor. I used it in text-mode for all my webdev editing (except ASP.NET) back when I used Windows.

Comment: ok!! it´s not only an editor is a WYSIWYG and an editor. I will change my commend :)

Answer (score 0):

For web development you can use an editor called Bluefish.

http://bluefish.openoffice.nl/

> Bluefish is targeted towards
>   programmers and webdesigners, with
>   many options to write websites,
>   scripts and programming code. Bluefish
>   supports many programming and markup
>   languages, and it focuses on editing
>   dynamic and interactive websites. See
>   [features](http://bluefish.openoffice.nl/features.html) for an extensive overview

You can install this from the command line using the following command

```
sudo apt-get install bluefish
```

[image]

Comment: where it will show after installation using given command.Thanks

Comment: Can we find in this end tag of particular tag?