# Dreamweaver alternative in ubuntu?

Tags: software-recommendation, html, css

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a Dreamweaver HTML editor replacement?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/7391/is-there-a-dreamweaver-html-editor-replacement)

I had been using Dreamweaver in Windows.
Recently I shifted to Ubuntu, there I cant find any good alternative to Dreamweaver.

So I decided to use Firebug but Its good for editing CSS, Javascript. I dont find it useful for editing HTML (in place).
1. Is there any way that can enable inplace editing of text in local webpages?

The problem I faced with firebug is that I am unable to save the edited CSS files or js files.
2. Is there any way that can enable saving of edited data in firebug?

**Edit 1: If I rename a site in dreamweaver it updates other pages which involve link to that site. Is it available in any software?**