# Alternatives to Adobe Products

Tags: adobe

I'm looking for alternatives of Adode products, such as Dreamweaver or Flash.

I thought to run them on Wine, but I'm sure it wouldn't work.

Thanks

Comment: Why is this question being downvoted? It may be a duplicate but the question was clear.

Comment: You should really ask separate questions for each product, Adobe has this [huge page](http://www.adobe.com/products/) of products, it'd be impossible to answer this question with one complete answer.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Dreamweaver alternative in ubuntu?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/38343/dreamweaver-alternative-in-ubuntu)

Answer (score 2):

Dreamweaver runs nicely on Wine. A native alternative would probably be nvu - i haven't tested it though.
As for Flash, it also runs nicely on Wine , with the only exception being the CS4 version.

Have you even checked wine's page before being sure that they wouldn't work?

Comment: JFYI, Nvu is still not as powerful or useful as Dreamweaver at current stage.

Comment: NVU is no longer actively developed IIRC - development has shifted to [KompoZer](http://kompozer.net/).

Comment: I just read about it on winehq's part about dreamweaver

Answer (score 0):

For Dreamweaver, you can use BlueGriffon. For Flash, you can try Lightspark.

Comment: There is an "I" at the end of your answer - could it be that you sent it without finishing it by mistake?

Comment: No, it's just a mistake. It's something like 6 A.M. in my country, so I sleep a little bit on my keyboard. x)

Answer (score 0):

I have worked with Dreamweaver 8, Flash 8 and Dreamweaver CS4 (portable) with out any problems... 
Anyway there are many open-source softwares that are better than windows apps.
suggestions by me ->
**web designing** - quanta plus, nvu...
**developing** - Geany, komodo IDE, Eclipse, Netbeans...

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a native Dreamweaver alternative, [Aptana](http://www.aptana.com/) is the closest I've found to a halfway decent replacement... but I ended up running a Windows XP Virtual Machine through [VirtualBox](http://www.virtualbox.org/) for adobe programs.

Answer (score 0):

This can be helpful for your Dreamweaver alternative, [Dreamweaver alternative in ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/38343/dreamweaver-alternative-in-ubuntu/48808#48808) transcribed here for your convenience. But if you find a Flash alternative please let me know, have been looking for it since 3 years ago and no success.

> Your question seems to be a little bit ambiguous.
>
> First of all and related to the alternative to Dreamweaver, I found
>   all the suggestions of all the other answers excellent, but when
>   looking for an alternative to Dreamweaver, the closest application
>   -for me- it was the [Amaya](http://www.w3.org/Amaya/) Project. Which seems to be richest than
>   other alternatives and a little bit more sophisticated than the
>   Kompozer.
>
> A screenshot from the official web is here for you to see it in
>   action:
>
> [image]
>
> Additional screenshots can be reached by clicking the next link:
>   http://www.w3.org/Amaya/screenshots/Overview.html
>
> You may find it a little bit unstable, or at least it was for me but
>   it may also fit your needs.
>
> After playing with WYSIWYG editors, I prefered direct encoding with
>   BlueFish but it is not a WYSIWYG editor.
>
> And about the suggestions for your issue with the firebug I can't say
>   anything, sorry.
>
> Please let us know how did you do if you give Amaya a chance.
>
> Good luck!
>
> Edit
>   == After installing Amaya, I find it yet far from stable but somehow
>   it seems to have a better features than other applications, if you
>   consider that other software are simple Text Editors and Amaya is like
>   a WYSIWYG editor.
>
> I tested what you said in your comment and I found that Amaya don't
>   even get noticed that something changed in the files/folders
>   structure/name. Which won't fit your needs related to this.
>
> In the next screenshot you can see I renamed the "resources" folder to
>   "resources1" and Amaya is yet showing it as "resources" and there is
>   no way to force it refresh. Even after restarting the software and
>   loading the project again, Amaya won't notice it.
>
> [image]

I am following your question in the hope to somebody drop off an alternative for the Flash.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing to substitute Adobe Flash on Linux except probably commerical Anime Studio, and even then I'm not sure you will have anything but pure .swf exporter which isn't very helpful.