# Is there an IDE with Inbuilt Browser and terminal?

Tags: software-recommendation, ide

I'm looking for an IDE which helps me reduce my Alt-Tabbing. At any given time, I've got a Chromium session open (for testing my application), a gedit/geany session for editing, and a dedicated terminal for git etc.

I remember that there was something like this in Visual Studio and Expression Studio. I've been through Komodo Editor, Eclipse, Bluefish, Anjuta but it seems that none of them have an **integrated browser**. Also I do not like the inbuilt terminal of geany (can never seem to restart it after a misplaced <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>.

Just to be clear, I do not want a HTML preview mode (offered by Bluefish for eg) which allows me to *preview my HTML*. I need a full-fledged browser (with JS,DOM support) embedded in tabs.

I would love if an editor offered these three things (*editor*, *terminal*, and *browser*) in a tabbed View. Allowing multiple terminals is a big plus.

Is there such an IDE available?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## [Redcar](https://github.com/redcar/redcar)

> A Ruby text editor written in Ruby from the ground up runs on JRuby (a fast, compatible
> Ruby implementation) is cross-platform (Linux, Mac OS X, Windows)
> highly extensible Some Redcar features:
>
> supports Textmate themes and snippets split screen mode syntax
> checking for many languages built in REPLs for Ruby, Groovy, Clojure
> and Mirah.

It has got an unstable terminal plugin, and an inbuilt browser as well (both of which open in tabs)

[image: Redcar Terminal]

Answer (score 4):

I think a better solutuion to your alt-tabbing problem would be, instead of trying to find an IDE which integrates all the things you need (what about an IRC client? Skype?) - is to use a window manager which helps you to organize your windows in a way which eliminates alt-tabbing and provides instant access to all your windows.

Have a look at some tiling window managers - I personally use [Xmonad](http://xmonad.org/) but there are a few others.

This way you will be able to use "real" programs - a real browser, a real terminal client - instead of their embedded versions.

Here's a picture from xmonad.org:

[image: xmonad running on 3 monitors]

Answer (score 2):

Geany has a built-in terminal in the Message window. As far as I'm aware, there is no way to add a browser to a tab, but it is possible to load a page in a new browser window and have it focus.

I personally just move my current applications to the top of the launcher so that I can use super+1 for Geany and super+2 for my application, for instance. That way, it's just as easy to switch between applications than it is to switch between tabs.

It should be possible to make a plugin to have a webkit in a tab in Geany, but I don't know of any such plugin.

Comment: I just switched my terminal to `gnome-terminal` and it seems quite better, but still its nowhere as good as multiple terminals inside geany tabs. 

Do you know of any geany plugin that creates its own tabs? I might try to develop something of the sort.

Comment: I don't, but then I've also never looked for Geany plugins.

Comment: geany already has a webkit based browser plugin named `webhelper`. I think the package name is `geany-plugin-webhelper` http://plugins.geany.org/webhelper.html

Comment: ^It opens in the bottom pane.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you also have a look at Light Table, one of the top 10 from KickStarter.  They have an excellent demo on their home page here: http://lighttable.com/

Comment: Does it meet the requirements outlined in the question?

Comment: The demo shows the imbedded browser and the feature list is above it.  I don't see a console but I think it may be there.

Comment: The demo shows a terminal?

Comment: No terminal.  I see they have issue #533 as a feature request for a shell in a tab. No one has been assigned to it yet. https://github.com/LightTable/LightTable/issues/533