# Why is the Web Preview in Geany slow to load?

Tags: geany

I hope it's okay to ask questions about Geany here... I see there's a Geany tag, but I don't know if there are any restrictions on what kind of questions are acceptable.

I just tried using Geany today for CSS editing because it was [recommended here on AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/59474/css-editor-with-real-time-preview-and-selector-localization). It is pretty cool and with the "Web Preview" plugin, it gives me the real time CSS preview that I was hoping for.

But, it's been frustrating me because when I save the CSS or HTML file I am working on, it takes a long time to load. A "long time" in this context is something like 5 seconds, which gets very aggravating when you are making changes and saving files rapidly in order to compare and contrast different CSS settings.

Is there a setting or something I can change to reduce or remove this lag? Is it a settings issue or just a bug?

Comment: hmm everything works fine when I save files... Do you save your files on an external Hard-drive?

Comment: It's probably best to change your workflow. 1) Open the HTML file in your browser. 2) Open the same file (plus the CSS file) in Geany. 3) Make your changes in Geany & save. 4) Press F5 to refresh the page in your browser and see the changes immediately.

Comment: @TomBrossman: Thanks for the suggestion, but that kind of flipping back and forth isn't really any different from having a text editor and browser open at the same time. It's that many more clicks and switching windows, which is what I'm hoping to reduce. Much like having a 5 second delay, having to switch windows back and forth and click reload after every change becomes aggravating with enough repetition.

Comment: @MrSeed: I'm saving to a local SSD drive on my laptop. I don't think the hardware can be the issue. It's a new laptop with pretty high specs.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a little late, but this refreshes the page every xx seconds, maybe that is usefull, change it to 3 for example and save and you only have to wait max 3 seconds and not have to switch between pages(if on 2 screens or something)

`<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="xx">`

(put it between the      head /head tags)

Arend-Jan